# How to restarts the app from splash when app clears data

Tags: android, android-studio, service

When i keep my App in the recent apps for about more than 30 minutes and after 30 minutes i open the same app from recent Apps. When i tried to open the same app after some times it open the same activity or Fragment but data is being cleared , So it actually restarts the Same Fragment or Activity . I am not able to retain the data in Fragment in App Android 7.0+ devices but working fine below Android 6 Devices So, How can i know about the life cycle of app so How can i handle so that i can restart the app from beginning .

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem in Android. One way would be to check if your data is present. Something like:

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myModel = new MyModel();
    //...
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (myModel == null) { //This means your activity is resumed after a period of time.
        finishAffinity();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

This will work, however this is not an exact way of addressing such problem. By the way you need to consider some issues like what happens to your whole app when `finishAffinity()` is called. A better solution lays in `savedInstanceState`. You can save the state of your Activity/Fragment on destroy, and restore at recreation:

```
 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
   outState.putString("data", "data to be saved");
   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        String data = savedInstanceState.getString("data");
        //Use the data to restore your Fragmetn/Activity
    }
}
```